# How to handle URLs that aren't controlled by a service worker

Tags: service-worker, fetch-api

My strategy for service worker is if the url matches some particular format then only service worker should intercept it ,otherwise browser should handle it as it does normally ,

for all cases i am using evt.respondWith(), to intercept it and serve a custom response , but what should i do if the url does not match any of the format

I have couple of option and all of them works , but i am not sure which one is logically correct

1)do nothing , means i am having if conditions for checking each of the defined format inside the fetch method but if they do not match i do nothing , i dont have any "else" condition.In this case browser is fetching the page normally , but i am not sure if it is correct , what is actually happening , is cookies getting passed ?

2)inside the else method i have `fetch(event.request, { credentials: 'include' });`
this also works , i am not sure if i need to include the credential clause here , as per my understanding not service worker but browser is  handling the request here , so it will automatically include the cookies . Please correct me if i am wrong here .

3)`event.respondWith(fetch(event.request, { credentials: 'include' }));`

This also works, i think since i am using event.respondWith, here i need to include the credential explicitly(again i am not sure).But my doubt is do i need to use `event.respondWith` here. What i know about `event.respondWith`is that, we use this only if we want to serve a custom response for a fetch event .As we want these requests to be handled as it is , do we need to use `event.respondWith` here ?

All of my confusions are coming from my lack of knowledge about `event.respondWith()`, could somebody please explain , exactly when should i use 
it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[event.respondWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent/respondWith) allows you to respond to a network request with a response that you create (either by using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), or the [Cache API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache), or even created manually with the [Response constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/Response)).

If you don't call it in the `fetch` event handler, the browser will handle the request.

If you call it with `fetch(event.request)`, it's basically the same as letting the browser handle it (because `fetch` is going to perform exactly the same request the browser would have performed if you hadn't called `event.respondWith`).

Note that `event.respondWith` will respond with the value you pass to it or with the value that the promise you pass to it is resolved to.

```
event.respondWith(new Response('Some body.'));

event.respondWith(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve(new Response('Some body.'));
  }, 1000);
}));
```

Comment: if i don't do anything(have no fetch(event.request)),then also browser handles the request , is it implied then  ?                                            Which one is most appropriate here among 1,2,3 ?                                                     and what is the rule for including the credential , when should i include it ?for 2 or 3 or both ?

Comment: Yes, if you don't call it the browser will handle the request. I think there's no "appropriate one", they're all correct.
You don't need to use the `credentials` parameter, it's a property of the request (`event.request`) that the browser did already set.

Comment: i don't need to include it even when i am using event.respondWith()?Then when exactly do we need this parameter  ?

Comment: @user17981 you don't need it in this case because the request object has been created by the browser itself and you simply want to do what the browser wants.
If you create a request yourself, then you need to decide whether you want to include cookies or not.

Comment: It's worth noting that the logic you use to determine whether or not to call `event.respondWith()` needs to be synchronous. In practice, this means that things like URL comparisons are fine, but anything that requires asynchronous usage of the Cache Storage or IndexedDB APIs won't work. See https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/service-worker/multiple-handlers/service-worker.js#L14